# What type of M.2 SSD is this?

Tags: ssd

I bought a Samsung M.2  SSD from an online shopping site. To my biggest surprise what I got is this picture.

[image]

It’s just not M.2 interface. It’s some kind of RAM or PCI slot like interface with I guess 64 pins on the edge of the PCB.

Does any such interface ever exists for M.2 SSDs? I strongly feel it’s a serious manufacturing mistake unless there really exists any such interface ever?

Could someone please explain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a higher-quality picture?

Comment: A link, part number, and/or better picture would be useful. Also, what M.2 did you order, they come in various form factors (2230, 2242, 2260, 2280, 22110, and socket type of B, M B&M, or type 3)

Comment: @acejavelin 850 Evo only came in a specific size

Comment: Model number was MZ-N5E250 @acejavelin, does any of the form factors you mentioned above come with 64 pin interface as what I got something vaguely similar to RAM ? Fortunately the seller has accepted the return for a replacement.

Comment: No... I am pretty sure you got something you weren't supposed to, a custom product or manufacturing defect. I would contact the seller or manufacturer. All M.2 devices I have seen have a small one or two notched connector on the short (22mm) side, never anything on the long side. Granted, I probably haven't seen every possible hardware interface, but that is not M.2